# Как из кнопок в QDialog вывести значения в программу Python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qdialog

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QDialog
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from docx.api import Document


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("gui.ui", self)
        self.Browse.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)
        self.Browse1.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles1)
        self.Browse2.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles2)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.get_number_of_points)
        self.Processing_button.clicked.connect(self.process)

    def browsefiles(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
        self.filename.setText(fname[0])
        return fname[0]

    def browsefiles1(self):
        fname1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
        self.filename1.setText(fname1[0])
        return fname1[0]

    def browsefiles2(self):
        fname2 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
        self.filename2.setText(fname2[0])
        return fname2[0]

    def get_number_of_points(self):
        value = self.spinBox.value()
        return value

    def process(self):
        # Входные файлы
        datafile = Path(r"test.xlsx")  # Excel-файл опыта
        protocol = Path(r"prot.docx")  # Файл протокола измерений
        processed_data = Path(r'out.xlsx')  # Файл с обработанными данными

        # Вставка шапки в Excel-файл
        header = pd.read_excel('Header.xlsx', header=0)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datafile, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
        header.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startcol=-1)
        writer.close()

        # Считывание протокола
        document = Document(protocol)
        tables = document.tables
        df = pd.DataFrame()

        for table in document.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
                df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)
        df = df[1:]
        df.columns = ['№', 'U, В', 'I, A', 'Время', 'Комментарии']
        protocol_time = df['Время'].values
        voltage = df['U, В'].tolist()
        for i in range(len(protocol_time)):
            if protocol_time[i] == '':
                protocol_time = np.delete(protocol_time, np.s_[i:])
                voltage = np.delete(voltage, np.s_[i:])
                break

        # Считывание данных эксперимента с Excel-файла
        data = pd.read_excel(datafile)
        Time = data['Time'].values
        dT = data['dT2'].tolist()
        q = data['q_h'].tolist()

        # Обработка эксперимента
        # Приведение времени к нормальному виду
        TimeArray = []
        for k in range(len(Time)):
            time_string = Time[k].astype(str).split('T')
            time_string.pop(0)
            timestr = ''.join(time_string)[:5]
            TimeArray.append(timestr)

        # Поиск совпадений времени в протоколе и файле эксперимента и добавление индексов этих совпадений в массив
        expindex = []
        for i in range(len(protocol_time)):
            for j in range(len(TimeArray)):
                if protocol_time[i] == TimeArray[j]:
                    expindex.append(j)
                    break
        expindex.pop(0)

        # Поиск максимального значения КТП перед кризисом
        for i in range(len(q)):
            if q[i] == max(q):
                expindex.append(i)

        N = self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBox.value())  # Осреднение по N точкам (N секунд)
        dT_out = []
        q_out = []
        for elem in expindex:
            mean_dT = 0
            mean_q = 0
            for i in range(elem, elem - N, -1):
                mean_dT += dT[i]
                mean_q += q[i]
            dT_out.append(mean_dT / N)
            q_out.append(mean_q / N)

        # Запись результата обработки в файл
        outf = pd.DataFrame({'Time': protocol_time,
                             'q': q_out,
                             'dT': dT_out,
                             'U': voltage})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(processed_data, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='new')
        outf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Обработка')
        writer.close()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Создаём виджет Qt — окно.
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
# Запускаем цикл событий.
app.exec()
```

Код выше отрисовывает окно и выполняет обработку 3-х подаваемых ему файла. 
Как сделать так , чтобы названия файлов и кол-во точек со спин-бара подавалось в программу (функцию `def process(self)`), вместо уже заданных параметров.

Скрин интерфейса:[image: скрин интерфейса]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, вы должны предоставлять [**минимально-воспроизводимый пример**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Вы этого не сделали и это не хорошо.

Учитывая что это ваш первый вопрос, я попробую вам помочь.

Проверьте:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QDialog
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from docx.api import Document


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("gui.ui", self)
        self.Browse.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)
        self.Browse1.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles1)
        self.Browse2.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles2)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.get_number_of_points)
        self.Processing_button.clicked.connect(self.process)
        self.spinBox_value = 0

    def browsefiles(self):
# -----------> v <------------------------------------------------------------
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        if fname:    
#            self.filename.setText(fname[0])
            self.filename.setText(fname)
        else:
            self.filename.setText('')        
#        return fname[0]             

    def browsefiles1(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
        if fname:    
#            self.filename1.setText(fname[0])
            self.filename1.setText(fname)
        else:
            self.filename1.setText('')  

    def browsefiles2(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open file', r"C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\Опыты")
        if fname:    
#            self.filename2.setText(fname[0])
            self.filename2.setText(fname)
        else:
            self.filename2.setText('') 

# -------------------------------> vvvvvvvvv <--------------------------------------
    def get_number_of_points(self, new_value):
#        value = self.spinBox.value()
        self.spinBox_value = new_value                                         # +++
#        return value

    def process(self):
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if not self.spinBox_value or \
           not self.filename.text() or \
           not self.filename1.text() or \
           not self.filename2.text(): 
           
            # что-то пощло не так
            return
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
        # Входные файлы
        '''
        datafile = Path(r"test.xlsx")       # Excel-файл опыта
        protocol = Path(r"prot.docx")       # Файл протокола измерений
        processed_data = Path(r'out.xlsx')  # Файл с обработанными данными
        '''
# ---------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------------
        datafile = self.filename.text()                                   # !!! +++
        protocol = self.filename1.text()                                  # !!! +++
        processed_data = self.filename2.text()                            # !!! +++      
        

        # Вставка шапки в Excel-файл
        header = pd.read_excel('Header.xlsx', header=0)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datafile, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
        header.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startcol=-1)
        writer.close()

        # Считывание протокола
        document = Document(protocol)
        tables = document.tables
        df = pd.DataFrame()

        for table in document.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
                df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)
        df = df[1:]
        df.columns = ['№', 'U, В', 'I, A', 'Время', 'Комментарии']
        protocol_time = df['Время'].values
        voltage = df['U, В'].tolist()
        for i in range(len(protocol_time)):
            if protocol_time[i] == '':
                protocol_time = np.delete(protocol_time, np.s_[i:])
                voltage = np.delete(voltage, np.s_[i:])
                break

        # Считывание данных эксперимента с Excel-файла
        data = pd.read_excel(datafile)
        Time = data['Time'].values
        dT = data['dT2'].tolist()
        q = data['q_h'].tolist()

        # Обработка эксперимента
        # Приведение времени к нормальному виду
        TimeArray = []
        for k in range(len(Time)):
            time_string = Time[k].astype(str).split('T')
            time_string.pop(0)
            timestr = ''.join(time_string)[:5]
            TimeArray.append(timestr)

        # Поиск совпадений времени в протоколе и файле эксперимента и добавление индексов этих совпадений в массив
        expindex = []
        for i in range(len(protocol_time)):
            for j in range(len(TimeArray)):
                if protocol_time[i] == TimeArray[j]:
                    expindex.append(j)
                    break
        expindex.pop(0)

        # Поиск максимального значения КТП перед кризисом
        for i in range(len(q)):
            if q[i] == max(q):
                expindex.append(i)

#        N = self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBox.value())  
# +++
        N = self.spinBox_value                                          # !!! +++

        dT_out = []
        q_out = []
        for elem in expindex:
            mean_dT = 0
            mean_q = 0
            for i in range(elem, elem - N, -1):
                mean_dT += dT[i]
                mean_q += q[i]
            dT_out.append(mean_dT / N)
            q_out.append(mean_q / N)

        # Запись результата обработки в файл
        outf = pd.DataFrame({'Time': protocol_time,
                             'q': q_out,
                             'dT': dT_out,
                             'U': voltage})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(processed_data, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='new')
        outf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Обработка')
        writer.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```